# Python error - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning python so this might sound simple, I am trying to run the code below but I keep getting the error message shown, any thoughts on what could be causing it?

```
from geopy import geocoders
import csv

g_api_key = 'my_google_api_key'
g = geocoders.GoogleV3(g_api_key)

costco = csv.reader (open('costcolimited.csv'), delimiter = ',')

# Print header
print "Address, City, State, Zip Code, Latitude, Longitude"
for row in costco:
   full_addy = row[1]+ "," + row[2]+ "," + row[3] + "," + row[4]
   place, (lat,lng) = list (g.geocode(full_addy, exactly_one=FALSE))[0]
   full_addy + "," + str(lat) + "," + str(lng)
```

The error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\geocodelocations.py", line 12, in <module>
full_addy = row[1]+ "," + row[2]+ "," + row[3] + "," + row[4]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Remember that the first element in `row` is `row[0]`, not `row[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by referring element out of list range. From your code, it is probably because you start counting element from `1`. Remember that in python list, index starts from `0`. If this is your situation, then shift indexes in

```
full_addy = row[1]+ "," + row[2]+ "," + row[3] + "," + row[4]
```

to

```
full_addy = row[0]+ "," + row[1]+ "," + row[2] + "," + row[3]
```

Otherwise, check your data structure and make sure it is matched with your code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your CSV file has four columns. Try checking if `len(row) >= 4`. If it contains you can go on with your code, but the first item in a Python list is referenced by 0 index.

Try something like this:

```
for row in costco:
   if len(row) < 4:
          print "Invalid file!"
          break
   full_addy = row[0]+ "," + row[1]+ "," + row[2] + "," + row[3]
   place, (lat,lng) = list (g.geocode(full_addy, exactly_one=FALSE))[0]
   full_addy + "," + str(lat) + "," + str(lng)
```